# sdkperf_java takes forever to launch multiple clients while sdkperf_mqtt is instantaneous

Tags: solace

Trying to test message delivery to multiple clients and found that sdkperf_java takes about 30 seconds per client before receiving messages.

```
./sdkperf_java.sh -cip=HOST -cu default@vpn-1 -cp default -stl=topics/data -cc=20
```

The MQTT version of sdkperf takes maybe 5 seconds to subscribe for hundreds of clients.

```
./sdkperf_mqtt.sh -cip=mqtt://HOST:PORT -stl=topics/data -cc=925
```

As I am trying to stress test with both types of connections, is there anything I can do about the launch time?  I need hundreds of clients running the java integration, but the spin-up time is an issue.

Comment: I'm running Fedora 24

Comment: Can you clarify what version of sdkperf_java and sdkperf_mqtt you are using, as well as the router version? Are these commands run from the same host? It is unexpected that sdkperf_java takes that long to connect 20 clients.

Comment: sol-sdkperf-mqtt-7.2.5.4, sol-sdkperf-7.2.2.29

Comment: Router Version: VMR 7.2

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are seeing with that version of SDKperf. I am able to connect 20 clients instantaneously. Is it possible to try a newer version sdkperf_java, or enable the debug logs for sdkperf and provide them here? Thanks!